# Web scraping in R not matching the website I am scraping from

Tags: r, web-scraping, forex

I am trying to web scrape from the forex factory. This is the specific link: https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar?day=apr3.2023. I have written R code but the output I get is not the same displayed in the link. I am not sure if it is a time zone error, a mistake in my code or something I am not aware of.

Here is the code I have written:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar?day=apr3.2023"

date <- sub(".*day=([[:alpha:]]{3}\\d{1,2})\\.(\\d{4})", "\\1 \\2", url)

page <- read_html(url)

time <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td.calendar__time") %>%
  html_text()

currency <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td.calendar__currency") %>%
  html_text()

event <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td.calendar__event") %>%
  html_text()

actual <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td.calendar__actual") %>%
  html_text()

forecast <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td.calendar__forecast") %>%
  html_text()

previous <- page %>%
  html_nodes("td.calendar__previous") %>%
  html_text()

calendar_df <- data.frame(date, time, currency, event, actual, forecast, previous)

head(calendar_df,3)
```

Currently this is the output my code is giving:

```
     date       time currency                         event                 actual
1 apr3 2023  \n2:30am   \nAUD\n        Commodity Prices y/y                -9.1%    
2 apr3 2023             \nCHF\n                     CPI m/m                    0.2% 
3 apr3 2023  \n2:45am   \nEUR\n   French Gov Budget Balance               -50.3B  
 forecast                  previous
1                             4.7%  
2    0.4%    \n            0.7%     
3          \n            -21.1B
```

What I am expected is shown in the forex factory link.

I was expecting to get the exact same output as displayed in the forex factory link, but this is not the case. The first entry of the code output is not the same as the entry in forex factory. Moreover, all the times are completely incorrect. I am not sure how to troubleshoot. My R is in the Europe/Madrid time zone and so is my forex factory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide what output your code is giving vs. what output you expect?

Comment: To me your output looks very much like on the forex link with the exception of the `\n`s.

Comment: @MartinGal They are quite similar but the entries are not the same and the times are different. Also, what do you mean by \n s?

Comment: @RobertoEmileTello For example `\n2:30am` contains `\n`. And if i take a look at the link, the first three entries are exactly the ones shown in your question.

Comment: @MartinGal I am not sure if we are seeing the same entries on forex factory then, maybe we are in different time zones. The first two entries refer to JPY and the third to CNY. On the other hand, in my output the first three entries refer to the AUD, CHF and EUR. Also the first entry on forex factory has a time of 1:50am whereas my code shows that it is 2:30am.

Comment: (1) The helps says: `Forex Factory automatically defaults to New York time zone (Eastern Time, US & Canada) during your first visit, but will adjust automatically if your system clock has a different setting.` Since rvest won't save any cookies it's always the "first" visit, thus the NY time zone. (2) I noticed a CSV / JSON / XML weekly export on the site. Perhaps you can download previous weeks without a need for scraping?

Comment: @MartinGal I also noticed the weekly export but I want about 10 years of historical data and downloading each week is inconvenient and time consuming, but if its the only way to do it I suppose I could. However, I just changed my time zone in forex factory to New York and now the times match up. I did not know rvest did not save cookies and thought it was a problem with R. Thank you very much for the help.